# How to use Azurite with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: azure-storage, visual-studio-2022

I have a project that requires Azure Storage and I am trying to use Azurite as a local emulator for development. Previously, I have been using the Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v5.10, which can easily be run from the Search bar. However, I am having difficulties setting up and running Azurite with Visual Studio 2022.

For more information, I don't have `Connected Service` appearing in my `Solution Explorer`. And when I right-click a project and select `Add`, the `Connection Service` is deactivated.

I have a multi-project ASP .NET MVC solution, mostly running .NET Framework 4.8.

Could anyone provide some guidance on how to set up and run Azurite with Visual Studio 2022? Is there a preferred way to integrate it with Visual Studio or any recommended best practices for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe include a screenshot of your solution explorer? Also what is the project type (asp.net core web API, console application, etc?)

Comment: @TimothyG. I can't add a screenshot as it is a large solution. but I have added further information:
"I have a multi-project ASP .NET MVC solution, mostly running .NET Framework 4.8"

Comment: @egillanton - If you cannot add screenshot of the complete solution,just add the part where the connected service is deactivated.Need to know y it is deactivated for you.

Comment: You might have missed installing few components for VS2022.Modify VS2022 => Click on Individual Components and select all the required components and modify.

Comment: Check the option for [Azure development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07oC0.png) and modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Visual Studio Installer` => `Visual Studio` => `Modify` => `Individual components`,  I have unchecked the `.NET Framework 4.8 SDK` => `Remove` => `Modify`.

You can see that the components related to Azure resource have been removed.

[image]

- Now when I try to add the `Connected Services`, I can see the option to `Manage Connected Services` but the Connected Services window is not opened.

[image]

- If you select the `Azure development`/ `.NET Framework 4.8 SDK`(under Individual components) and modify VS, the components related to Azure resources will be added.

[image]

- Modify VS with above changes.
- Now Iam able to see and add Azurite from  `Connected services`.

[image]

> Is there a preferred way to integrate it with Visual Studio or any recommended best practices for this?

Yes, this is the most easy and preferred way to add Azure resources.

If you still face issues, you can even integrate Azurite manually (but includes manual steps to follow which is not easy to configure).

The below screenshot is from Connected Services, try to install the specified packages manually.

[image]

***Packages to Install from NuGet Manager***

[image]

- Right click on the `Solution Explorer` => `Manage User Secrets`, secrets.xml will be created.
- Add the below settings in `secrets.xml`.

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <secrets ver="1.0">
    <secret name="Azurite" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    <secret name="Azurite:blob" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    <secret name="Azurite:queue" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
  </secrets>
</root>
```

- And 3 files with `serviceDependencies` prefix has to be added which contains the Azurite ConnectionID.

[image]

Refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#running-azurite-from-an-aspnet-project) for more details.